# MMS Agent VERY high data usage

Tags: mongodb-mms

I have an application which really does not have a lot of writes to a mongo replica set yet there is a constant 500Kb/s network traffic between members of the set, even over night when there is absolutely no traffic on the application. Surely this is not the heartbeats? What could possibly be using so much bandwidth?

SEE EDIT, this is not the replset but rather the MMS monitoring which is running on the same machine

Comment: Okay, so after much digging it seems it is not the replsets that is murdering the network but the MMS agent that draws 500Kb/s per replica set that it is monitoring, so if you have a single server running the MMS agent monitoring a number of replsets then before you know it you are pulling 5Mb/s NON STOP bandwidth???

Comment: This seems like an anomaly. The MongoDB support team has reached out to you privately to investigate the nature of this problem further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guys at mongo, it turns out that it is the log capture functionality.

If you are experiencing the same thing, log onto MMS and edit your host and turn off logs, bandwidth drops immediately.